# graphhopper Custom osm.pbf file

Tags: openstreetmap, graphhopper, mapsforge, osmosis

I have a database filled with my own data which I collected. I stored the data in a `pgsnapshot` databasis after which successfully exported via `Osmosis` to a `.pbf` file, osm tagged etc.

After this I give this file to graphhopper to generate the routing files, and have also created the Mapsforge `.map` file with `Osmosis` and this displays correctly. However, I can only route on a single track geometry and over two or more, I get the "route between locations cannot be found error". I did the same with a standard `OSM` `pbf` file and the routing works perfectly. So the question is, what can possible be different between my custom `pbf` file and a standard OSM pbf file that causes the routing on my data not to work over more than one track geometry? This happens throughout my data.

Furthermore, my data has been cleaned and snapped at all intersections at a tolerance of 0.00002. So I assume that all the tracks are connected.

Comment: `So I assume that all the tracks are connected`. Check it, e.g. with JOSM.

Comment: Will this hint help? https://discuss.graphhopper.com/t/how-to-get-the-osm-resource-reference-for-a-node-edge-in-the-match-result/200/12

Comment: All the tracks are connected, however I will try the suggestions and get back to you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, usging JOSM to validate the data seemed to do the trick.

Thanks for the help.